# Last Updated Item from Table

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

```
UniqueIndex         Item
521                          ABC
520                          ABC
519                          ABC
518                          ABC
517                          CDC
516                          CDC
515                          CDC
```

need T-SQL for result

```
521               ABC
517              CDC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this 2-columns dataset, you can just use aggregation:

```
select item, max(uniqueIndex) lastUniqueIndex
from mytable
group by item
```

If there are more columns that you want to display, then you can filter with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.uniqueIndex = (select max(t1.uniqueIndex) from mytable t1 where t1.item = t.item)
```

For performance here, consider an index on `(item, uniqueIndex)`.

You can also use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by item order by uniqueIndex desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: thanks. sorry I forgot to mention table has other columns too